# Cakephp : echo rows from an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp

Please bear in my mind this isn't originally my code so it's not crystal clear to me and help is extremely welcome as I'm lost.

I want to display rows from another table, but I'm facing some issues.
When I use

in controller :

```
$companies = $this->Users->Companies->find('list');
```

in view

```
echo $this->Form->input('companies._ids',['options' =>$companies,'multiple'=>'checkbox']);?>
```

I get all of my Company's table ids and names in these basic checkboxes.

However, as I want to use every rows and not just id and name, I try using :

```
$companies = $this->Users->Companies->find('all');
```

but this triggers two problems :
my datas are displayed in arrays like this :

```
{ "id": 2, "name": "Smith", "city": "Duisburg"}
```

and second problem : it skips the first row ! I have something with id 1, not showing when using `find('all')`, but showing when using `find('list')`

So how can I get every values and display them the way I want to ?

Comment: I haven't had the problem with missing the first row (yet..).  But yes I find that changing the 'find' options often sends back a different array which needs to be parsed differently.  It's.. cake :-).  Retrieve the 'all' data in a different array and use it separately?  It's not worth banging your head on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want different fields from the list you can specify that.

[Specify Fields for Find List](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)

```
$query = $this->Users->Companies->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'slug',
    'valueField' => 'title'
]);
$data = $query->toArray();

// Data now looks like
$data = [
    'first-post' => 'First post',
    'second-article-i-wrote' => 'Second article I wrote',
];
```